# Computed Property Macros with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm attempting to DRY up my application and move some functionality into macros with Ember CLI. After reading [this article](http://balinterdi.com/2014/05/22/make-your-own-computed-property-macro-in-emberjs.html), I thought I could get things working but I'm getting an `undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function` error when trying to use the macro with any arguments. If I don't pass any arguments, ember doesn't throw the error. To generate the file I'm using the command `ember generate util calc-array`

```
// utils/calc-array.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function calcArray(collection, key, calculation) {
    return function() {
        ...
    }.property('collection.@each');
}

// controller/measurements.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import calculate from '../../utils/calc-array';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    high: calculate(this.get('model'), 'value', 'high'),
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.get('model')` causes the problem - `this` points to global object, not controller instance. Pass the string (i.e. `model`) and use `this.get` inside computed property.

Also `collection.@each` will not work, it's not a valid path.

Summing it up:

```
 export default function calcArray(collectionPath, key, calculation) {
   return function() {
     var collection = this.get(collectionPath);
     ...
   }.property(collectionPath + '.@each');
 }
```